# trim dataframe in spark using last appearance of value in the column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe where I want to trim it by last appearance of value `Good` in column PDP. This is to consider rows 5 and below. Anything above row 5 does not matter.

```
+------+----+
|custId| PDP|
|  1001| New|
|  1002|Good|
|  1003| New| 
|  1004| New|
|  1005|Good|
|  1006| New|
|  1007| New|
|  1008| New|
|  1009| New|
+------+----+
```

What i need is this dataframe. Since last `Good` action happened on row 5th

```
+------+----+
|custId| PDP|
|  1001| New|
|  1002|Good|
|  1003| New| 
|  1004| New|
|  1005|Good|
+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df
  .filter($"PDP" === "Good")             // Filter good
  .select(max("custId").alias("maxId"))  // Find max id
  .crossJoin(df)
  .where($"custId" <= $"maxId")          // Filter records with id <= lastGoodId
  .drop("maxId")                         // Remove obsolete column
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the last row index with `Good` in `PDP` column, and then filter in only rows less than that index.

## custId

If your `custId` column contains increasing ids in sorted order then you can do the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val maxIdToFilter = df.filter(lower(col("PDP")) === "good").select(max(col("custId").cast("long"))).first().getLong(0)
df.filter(col("custId") <= maxIdToFilter).show(false)
```

## monotically_increasing_id

If your `custId` is not sorted and increasing order then you can use following logic

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfWithRow = df.withColumn("rowNo", monotonically_increasing_id())
val maxIdToFilter = dfWithRow.filter(lower(col("PDP")) === "good").select(max("rowNo")).first().getLong(0)
dfWithRow.filter(col("rowNo") <= maxIdToFilter).drop("rowNo").show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful